# Beginner Unix shell script issues

Tags: shell, unix

I'm working on an assignment that is a two part assignment. First we were asked to create a shell script called fileType.sh that is able to tell if a file is "Windows ASCII" type or "something else." I have completed that part and will display an example of what it's supposed to do below.

```
./fileType.sh ~cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat
 Windows ASCII
 ./fileType.sh /bin/cat
 Something else
 ./fileType.sh fileType.sh
 Something else 
 ./fileType.sh /usr/share/dict/words
 Something else
```

It works and here is the code for the fileType.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       
file="$1"
case $(file "$file") in
    *"ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" )
        echo "Windows ASCII"
    ;;
    * )
        echo "Something else"
    ;;
esac
```

Part two of this assignment wants us to:  In that same directory, write a script checkFiles.sh that can take multiple file paths from the command line and carries out the same analysis on each one, printing a line containing the file name, a colon, a blank, and then one of the two output strings from Stage 1, for each file in the command line.

For example,

```
./checkFiles.sh /usr/share/dict/words fileType.sh /home/cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat
/usr/share/dict/words: Something else
fileType.sh: Something else
/home/cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat: Windows ASCII
```

Here's the checkFiles.sh script that I have written.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                     
for i  in "$@"; do

    echo $i":" "`sh ./fileType.sh`" 

done
```

and here's my output when I run it.

```
./checkFiles.sh /usr/share/dict/words fileType.sh /home/cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat
/usr/share/dict/words: Something else
fileType.sh: Something else
/home/cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat: Something else
```

The error I get from my hw checker is: Failed when running: ./checkFiles.sh 'aardvark.cpp' 'bongo.dat' 'cat.dog.bak'. I'm going to test a .ccp and a .bak to see if it blows up my program or something. Does anyone else have any ideas? I have been working on this for quite sometime, any help would be great. Thanks!

Update: Ok, so after rerunning this command I get:

```
./checkFiles.sh /home/cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat
/home/cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat: Something else
```

But that's not correct! instead of saying "Something else" it should say "Windows ASCII." The problem is somewhere in my checkFiles.sh script. Changing somethings around now, but this is where I'm at so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your workhorse is missing the file name that you want to analyze.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i  in "$@"; do
    echo $i":" "$(sh ./fileType.sh $i)"
done
```

HTH

Comment: And it might be better to use: `echo "$i: $(sh ./fileType.sh "$i")"`; it avoids problems with file names that contain spaces.

Comment: There's no need to use process substitution.  Just do `echo -n "$i: "; ./fileType.sh $i`  If you want to be more portable (some echo don't support -n), use 'printf' instead of `echo -n`