# shell script that determines file type

Tags: shell

Having trouble with this problem, i could use some help ....

create a shell script, fileType.sh, that takes a single command line parameter, a file path (might be relative or absolute). The script should examine that file and print a single line consisting of the phrase

Windows ASCII

if the files is an ASCII text file with CR/LF line terminators, or

Something else

if the file is binary or ASCII with “Unix” LF line terminators.

For example:

./fileType.sh ~cs252/Assignments/ftpAsst/d3.dat

Windows ASCII

./fileType.sh /bin/cat

Something else

./fileType.sh fileType.sh

Something else

./fileType.sh /usr/share/dict/words

Something else

Your script should not produce any other output when given a legal path to an existing file. (It may produce anything you like if given an incorrect path to a non-existent file.)

New to Unix, I have some C++ experience.

This is what i have in my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
grep -r 'Windows ASCII' $1
if $(file == "ASCII TEXT");then
echo Windows ASCII
else
echo Something Else 
fi
```

this is my output:

./fileType.sh: 4: ./fileType.sh: [file: not found

Something Else

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -r "Windows ASCII" $1
if test "$( file "$1")" = ' ASCII text, with  CRFL line terminators'; then
echo Windows ASCII
else 
echo Something else
fi
```

my output now is just Something else when the file I am passing in should give an output of Windows ASCII ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beginner Unix shell script issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371010/beginner-unix-shell-script-issues)

Comment: Does `file` produce the leading space?  You would be much better off doing `if file "$1" | grep -q "ASCII text"; then`

Answer (score 2):

Your script is trying to execute a command named "[file".  That is not what you want.  Offering no advice about the advisability of this solution, but the syntax to implement what you seem to want is:

```
if test "$( file "$1" )" = 'ASCII TEXT'; then
```

or

```
if [ "$( file "$1" )" = 'ASCII TEXT' ]; then
```

`[` is a command (whether builtin to the shell or external is irrelevant), which is exactly the same as the command `test` except that it expects its last argument to be `]`.  It is a heinous kludge that was an attempt to make the syntax appear as if the brackets are tokens in the shell language.  IMO, it is far better to use `test` as it makes it clear that it is not part of the grammar.

Comment: Needs to be `"$( file "$1" )"` to correctly handle filenames with spaces, glob characters, etc.

Comment: I edited my script and that took care of the error messages, however I am still not getting the expected output. I am getting "something else" when I should be getting "Windows ASCII" ...

Comment: @Bryan Note that the comparison in `test` (`[ … ]`) is case-sensitive. Try to run `file` command in your terminal and then use the message you get. Also note that `file` is just a guesswork and may identify more than you need – e.g. a C source will be `ASCII C program text`.

Comment: I ran the file command in my terminal and file I was testing is a "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" so I adjusted my script to reflect this however I am still getting "Something Else" when I should be getting "Windows ASCII" as my output, I will post updated scrip ...

Comment: The string "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators" is hardly the same as the string "ASCII TEXT".

Answer (score 1):

The actual implementation requires that you interpret/test the result of the `file` return a bit more. William's answer pointed you in that direction. It is a bit unclear whether you are needing a solutions for traditional `shell` programming (as in **Bourne Shell**) or whether you are looking for a **Bash** (or equivalent) solution. Above, I guess the confusion surrounds the use of:

```
if test "$( file "$1" )" = 'ASCII TEXT'; then
```

While this will confirm for you that the file is text with `lf` separators, exclusive of all others, it does not give you a way to tell whether the file contains lines with `CRLF` line-ends or not (just that it is not 'ASCII TEXT'). To make the exclusive determination whether the file contains `CRLF` line-ends, you need to test the `file` output to find `CRLF`.

Regardless of the shell, the approach is the same. Capture the result of the `file` command, and test whether the result contains `CRLF`. The difference between shells is how you accomplish the test. The following examples provide a way to do the testing the **Bourne Shell** and the same again in **Bash** (note: there are many ways to accomplish the test in either, this is just one approach in each):

```
#!/bin/sh

line=`file -b "$1"`

## Bourne Shell
win=0
for i in $line; do                                # search for CRLF in $line
    if test `expr match "$i" "CRLF"` -gt 0 ; then
        win=1
        break
    fi
done

if test "$win" -eq 1 ; then 
    printf "Windows ASCII\n"
else
    printf "Something else\n"
fi

## BASH
if [[ "$line" =~ "CRLF" ]]; then                  # use substring operator
    printf "Windows ASCII\n"
else
    printf "Something else\n"
fi
```

**Example with/CRLF:**

```
$ ./Type.sh ../../utl/tst/config.win.ini
Windows ASCII
Windows ASCII
```

**Example with/LF:**

```
$ ./Type.sh ../../utl/tst/config.ini
Something else
Something else
```

Comment: I have edited my shell to reflect the Bourne version above, however I now realize that I need to search for two strings "ASCII" and "CRLF". So I have been trying to adjust the test line to search for two variables



     if test `expr match "$i" "CRFL" | expr match "$1" "ASCII"`                 -g 0; then
.....



I am using tcsh and basically I am trying to search for two varribles at the same time. In C++ I would use the "&&" operator. I don't know if unix has such an operator so I have tried to "pipe" them together.... with no luck.

Comment: You should be able to use `if test $(expr match "$i" "CRLF") -gt 0 -o $(expr match "$i" "ASCII") -gt 0 ; then`  If not, then use `if test $(expr match "$i" "CRLF") -gt 0 ; then ...stuff... elif $(expr match "$i" "ASCII") -gt 0 ; then ...stuff... fi`. **NOTE:** `$()` is used above because I can't use a backtick in this comment.